# Какие стандартные значания стоит писать в CSS файл?

Tags: css, шаблоны

Поясню свой вопрос: При создании сайта в современных тенденциях веб-разработки, какие стандартные значения вы считаете нужно писать в CSS файл, так сказать шаблонные, например обнуление padding и margin и т.п. Например если я собираюсь создать сайт с адаптивностью, то какие значения мне стоит написать в пустой css файл в самом начале работы? Я понимаю что бывают разные задачи и соответственно разные подходы, но меня интересует ваше мнение. Другими словами: как выглядит ваш униварсальный css шаблон?

Answer (score 5):

Можно использовать css reset, типа [Eric Meyer’s “Reset CSS” 2.0](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) или [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). Они обнуляют значения, чтобы css был кроссбраузерным.
Более мощнее можно использовать [Web Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/starter-kit/) (ну или найти в [google.ru](http://google.ru) по фразе `Starter kit`)

Answer (score 2):

От себя добавлю:

1. [Google Web Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/starter-kit/) — полноценный фреймворк от Google
2. [godlike.css](https://www.kobzarev.com/makeup/godlike-css/) — небольшая библиотека (кстати, я участвовал в ее разработке), которая помогает разработчикам  легче справляться с ежедневными трудностями, с помощью обнуления стандартных стилей, фикса багов браузеров и добавления юзабилити. 
   xa